# Ruby on rails: cannot install FFI 1.1.5 and bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, x86-64

I am following the tutorial on [the rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top) and am on the third chapter (static pages). When I try to do the `bundle install` immediately under listing 3.1, the command throws an error message that indicates a failed linking. A snippet of the error is shown below:

```
Using bundler (1.2.1)
Using nokogiri (1.5.5)
Installing ffi (1.1.5) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby18 extconf.rb  
checking for ffi_call() in -lffi... yes checking for ffi_prep_closure()... yes 
checking for ffi_raw_call()... yes 
checking for ffi_prep_raw_closure()... yes 
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no 
checking for ruby_native_thread_p()... no 
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... no creating extconf.h 
creating Makefile
... 
... 
... 
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"    -fPIC -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -I/usr/lib64/libffi-3.0.10/include    -c LastError.c x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -shared -o ffi_c.so FunctionInfo.o MemoryPointer.o MethodHandle.o Platform.o Function.o LongDouble.o StructLayout.o StructByValue.o Struct.o Variadic.o ClosurePool.o Type.o Types.o ArrayType.o DynamicLibrary.o Thread.o Call.o Buffer.o StructByReference.o AbstractMemory.o ffi.o MappedType.o Pointer.o DataConverter.o LastError.o -L. -L/usr/lib64 -Wl,-R/usr/lib64 -L.-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--no-undefined     -Wl,-R -Wl,/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -lruby18 -lffi  -lffi   -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc 
Thread.o: In function `rbffi_thread_blocking_region': 
Thread.c:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `pthread_create' 
Thread.c:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `pthread_join' 
Thread.o: In function `cleanup_blocking_thread': Thread.c:(.text+0x239): undefined reference to `pthread_kill'
Thread.o: In function `rbffi_blocking_thread': Thread.c:(.text+0x271): undefined reference to `pthread_testcancel' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [ffi_c.so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/user/.gem/gems/ffi-1.1.5 for inspection. 
Results logged to /home/user/.gem/gems/ffi-1.1.5/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out 
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.1.5), and Bundler cannot continue. 
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.1.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

From what I can gather, this is easily solved by adding the right library for pthread (-lpthread). But my question is, where do I add this? I see a lot of questions for solving this problem on MAC OS X, but none for linux. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "dev-lang/ruby threads" to my package.use and rebuilding dev-lang/ruby